# Telegram get chat messages /posts - python Telethon

Tags: python, telethon

I am using Telethon and Python 3.6xx

Been able to retreive message from groups, no problem but when it comes to channels I am stuck.

```
dialogs = client(get_dialogs)
for chat in dialogs.chats:
   getmessage = client.get_messages(chat.id, limit=400)
   for message in getmessage:
        print(message.message)
```

I've searched the telethon documentation but most answers were in response to the old `get_message_history`.

When I'm trying with the following `chat.id = 1097988869` (news.bitcoin.com) I'm getting an error below (for groups the `chat.id` works fine):

> PeerIdInvalidError: An invalid Peer was used. Make sure to pass the right peer type

Comment: Do you w to get a message from the channel ?

Comment: Note that in recent versions of Telethon, `client.get_messages(chat, limit=400)` should work just fine.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

update :

in the new version of Telethon, @Lonami answer is best and use it.

############################################################

you can use this code for get messages :

```
client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                    api_id,
                    api_hash,
                    update_workers=1,
                    spawn_read_thread=False)
assert client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))

channel_username='tehrandb' # your channel
channel_entity=client.get_entity(channel_username)
posts = client(GetHistoryRequest(
    peer=channel_entity,
    limit=100,
    offset_date=None,
    offset_id=0,
    max_id=0,
    min_id=0,
    add_offset=0,
    hash=0))
# messages stored in `posts.messages`
```

Comment: Thank you Ali! just for anyone else who is a beginner like me, you can access the text of the channel message by adding `for message in posts.messages:
    print(message.message) `

Comment: You forgot `from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest`

Comment: Note for other people coming here, in newer versions of Telethon, the library is async and this code will fail. It is necessary to properly await everything or `import telethon.sync`.

Comment: Not every megagroup has a username, in my case it is None, how do you do this in that case?

Comment: Also, can you please share how do you get around the 100 messages limit?

Answer (score 44):

The accepted answer is good, but recent versions of Telethon let you achieve the same more easily. This will iterate over *all* messages in `chat` (for this example we use `telethon.sync` to avoid typing out `async`):

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
        print(message.sender_id, ':', message.text)
```

Where the variables should be obvious, for example (note these API values won't work, you need your own):

```
name = 'anon'
api_id = 123
api_hash = 'abcdefgh'
chat = 'me'
```

More examples using `async` are available in [`client.iter_messages`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.iter_messages) documentation.

Comment: This works with `Telethon==1.10.8` while the accepted answer raises an exception because `posts` no longer has an attribute `messages`.

Comment: @EliasStrehle `posts` still should have a `messages`, but maybe it's just missing the `await` call.

Comment: Is there a shortcut to forwarding all messages from a chat? I am trying to forward all messages from a chat, starting from oldest and going to newest

Comment: @Lonami how to get messages from channel or group. It says `ValueError: No user has "xxx" as username`

Answer (score 6):

that work for me!

api_hash from https://my.telegram.org, under API Development.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync

api_id = 'your api_id'
api_hash = 'your api_hash'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
channel_username = 'username'# your channel
for message in client.get_messages(channel_username, limit=10):
    print(message.message)
```

Comment: without passing limit parameter only the last message is seen. How to get all messages using get_messages

Answer (score 0):

I've used an extra parameter to search only for specific messages in the channel:

```py
search='cetvorosoban'

for message in client.get_messages(channel_username, limit=3, search='cetvorosoban'):
```